# Schema hasn't been registered for model \"ref\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

i'm new to typegoose , i am trying to populate the category field using ProductModel.find().populate('category') but the program throws that error: **Schema hasn't been registered for model "ref".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)** May I know what I am missing?

My product model:

```
import { getModelForClass, prop, Ref, plugin } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { Category } from './category.model';

export class Product {
  @prop({ required: true })
  public name?: string;

  @prop({ default: null })
  public photo?: string;

  @prop({ default: 0 })
  public rating?: number;

  @prop({ ref: () => Category, required: true })
  public category?: Ref<Category>;
}

export default getModelForClass(Product);
```

My category model:

```
import { getModelForClass, prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

export class Category {
  @prop({ required: true })
  public name?: string;

  @prop({ default: null })
  public photo?: string;
}

export default getModelForClass(Category);
```

I am using the first-time typegoose so I need a good explanation for this.

Comment: please provide what versions you have used (typescript, mongoose, typegoose) and also, did you follow all requirements for typegoose? (most common for this error is not having `es6` set in the tsconfig for `target`) see https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/quick-start-guide#requirements

Comment: @hasezoey thank you for your help, it was about es6 in tsconfig

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing your "modelOptions"?:

```
import { getModelForClass, prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

@modelOptions({ options: { customName: "Category_name" } })
export class Category {
  @prop({ required: true })
  public name?: string;

  @prop({ default: null })
  public photo?: string;
}

export default getModelForClass(Category);
```